# Deploy terraform to azure through a pipeline in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, terraform, azure-pipelines

I have deployed terraform to azure locally from the azure cli to success so I know the TF is working
I am now trying to build a pipeline to automate this process, however i get this error...

Error: Error building ARM Config: obtain subscription(xxxxxx) from Azure CLI: Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1

This error appears when the init is running in the pipeline.

This is what the pipeline looks like...

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages :
  - stage: validate
    jobs:
    - job: validate
      continueOnError: false
      steps:
      - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
        displayName: 'install'
        inputs:
          terraformVersion: '0.14.10'
      
      - bash: echo $(ls -latR)
        
      - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
        displayName: 'init'
        inputs:
          provider: 'azurerm'
          command: 'init'
          workingDirectory: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
          backendServiceArm: 'Service-Fabric'
          backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'fvs-uks-sf-rg-02'
          backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'fvsukssfstorage'
          backendAzureRmContainerName: 'fvs-uks-sf-backend01'
          backendAzureRmKey: 'terraform.tfstate'
              
      - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
        displayName: 'validate'
        inputs:
         provider: 'azurerm'
         command: 'validate'

      - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
        displayName: 'plan'
        inputs:
          provider: 'azurerm'
          command: 'plan'
          workingDirectory: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
          environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'test'
          environmentServiceNameAWS: 'AWS-Azure-VPN'
```

This is what the backend.tf looks like...

```
provider "azurerm" {
  alias   = "hub"
  subscription_id = "xxxxxxx"
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    subscription_id      = "xxxxxx"
    resource_group_name  = "xxxxxx"
    storage_account_name = "xxxxxx"
    container_name       = "xxxxxx"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

I have also set up a service connection to azure via a service principal, that when authenticated connects successfully.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I am yet to test the below. I am going to test this shortly and update the thread accordingly

Answer (score 2):

> Deploy terraform to azure through a pipeline in azure devops

This issue should be related to the authorization.

When we use the service connection to authorization, it use the Service Principal instead of username/password to authenticate.

Then according to the [terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/service_principal):

> If you're authenticating using a **Service Principal** then it **must have
> permissions to both Read and write all applications and Sign in and
> read user profile within the Windows Azure Active Directory API**.

Please try to add a API permission for your principal, which you used to create the service connection:

[image]

> Navigate to the Azure Active Directory overview within the Azure
> Portal and select the App Registrations blade. Locate your registered
> Application and click on its display name to manage it.
>
> Go to the API Permissions blade for the Application and click the "Add
> a permission" button. In the pane that opens, select "Azure Active
> Directory Graph" (under the Supported Legacy APIs subheading). Do not
> select "Microsoft Graph", as the provider does not currently make use
> of this API.
>
> Choose "Application Permissions" for the permission type, and check
> the permissions you would like to assign. The permissions you need
> will depend on which directory objects you are seeking to manage with
> Terraform. We suggest the following permissions:
>
> `Application.ReadWrite.All`
>
> `Directory.ReadWrite.All`